# MYSQL: Retrieve latest unique records

Tags: mysql

I have a table that logs rows where the member_id repeats.

### The column fields are:

**id:**            int(7) Primary key, Auto increment 
 
**member_id:**     int(7) Index 
**item_qt:**       int(7)

```
+----+-----------+---------+----------+
| id | member_id | item_qt |timestamp |
+----+-----------+---------+----------+
|553 | 107       | 10      | 00:17:53 |
+----+-----------+---------+----------+
|552 | 107       | 25      | 00:17:51 | 
+----+-----------+---------+----------+
|551 | 122       | 6       | 00:17:43 |
+----+-----------+---------+----------+
|550 | 122       | 9       | 00:17:22 |
+----+-----------+---------+----------+
|549 | 107       | 19      | 00:17:11 |
+----+-----------+---------+----------+
```

### First, **what query would retrieve these results?**

- select the latest unique rows

(This post gave me some direction)
[[Retrieve last (latest) distinct highest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227619/retrieve-last-latest-distinct-highest-value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227619/retrieve-last-latest-distinct-highest-value)

```
+----+-----------+---------+----------+
| id | member_id | item_qt |timestamp |
+----+-----------+---------+----------+
|553 | 107       | 10      | 00:17:53 |
+----+-----------+---------+----------+
|551 | 122       | 6       | 00:17:43 |
+----+-----------+---------+----------+
```

### Next, **How do you get this?**

```
+----+-----------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | member_id | item_qt |timestamp | item_qt_sum |
+----+-----------+---------+----------+-------------+
|553 | 107       | 10      | 00:17:53 | 54          |
+----+-----------+---------+----------+-------------+
|551 | 122       | 6       | 00:17:43 | 15          |
+----+-----------+---------+----------+-------------+
```

- sum the item_qt for a number of rows in < 5 minutes time

Comment: @rrrfusco: I updated my answer based on what you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t
JOIN ( SELECT MAX( id ) AS id, SUM( item_qt ) AS sum_item_qt
FROM table
WHERE `timestamp` >= DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 5
MINUTE )
GROUP BY member_id
)t2 ON t2.id = t.id
ORDER BY t.id DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how all this fits together as I don't 100% understand what you are asking...

To get the last row in the table

```
select top 1 * from [table] order by id desc
```

To sum a colum

```
select sum(item_qt) as SumItem_qt from [table]
```

For joins just google "inner join"

Sort desc is just order by column name desc

Comment: "SELEC TOP n" is a Microsoft SQL Server syntax.  It's not supported by the SQL standard, or other brands of RDBMS (except for Sybase, which shares common code with MS SQL Server).

Comment: I noticed that also. Seemed sort of odd. Not really familiar with MS SQL. :)

Comment: oops had my MS head on!

remove TOP 1 and add LIMIT 1 at end of SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

OK then use...

```
SELECT un.name, t.item_qt
FROM TABLE t
JOIN USERNAME un ON un.id = t.member_id
ORDER BY t.id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

You could also use say LIMIT 5 to get 5 records...

When you say slow what do you mean? There may appear to be a problem that we don't know about.
I suspect there may be lots of records and no indexes....

It may be wise to post the schema of both tables so we can help you further.... Also give an indication of number of rows in each table....

Comment: Hi Rippo. I appreciate the comments. Your SQL does not address a needed subquery and group by member_id, which I think is necessary. If you run an EXPLAIN on the SQL I posted Sep. 7 1:12, it runs fairly fast, but I am looking for a improved workaround, possibly with joins and union.
Indexes and schema are in the inital post. Records will increase to thousands.